# C confusion of printf, and gets method

Tags: c

Im new to C. I have a problem in understanding a piece of code.
What I don't understand are two things. The second argument of fgets is the maximum length of bytes can be stored in the buffer.
Why if I type more letters in the terminal and hit enter still the string is printed back in full. I am assuming that if the length of the string inserted in the console is larger than the buffer will overflow and the printf will work because it stops on the termination of the string, but then what it is the point of setting a max limit as second argument to fgets?

```
  #define buff_size 4

    //3.71 
     void good_echo(){ 
char buf[buff_size]; 
while(1) {
    char* p = fgets(buf, 8, stdin);
    if(p == NULL) {
        break;
    }
  printf("%s", p);
}
return;
 }
```

Comment: Do not conflate stdin and the terminal.  When you type data into your terminal, it is displayed back to you before your program ever sees it.  After you hit `return`, data is sent to your program.  The fgets will at that point only consume as much as it can.  What you see in the terminal as you type is totally unrelated to your program.

Comment: Is your question about the terminal echo, or is it about the discrepancy between the 8 that you are passing as the 2nd argument to `fgets` and the size of the buffer (which is only 4)?  If the latter, that is simply a manifestation of undefined behavior.  You have overwritten the bounds of the buffer, and anything can happen, including the behavior you would expect had the buffer been large enough.

Comment: Side note: The `if` statement would not be necessary if you wrote `while ( fgets( buf, 8, stdin ) != NULL )` instead.

Comment: Side note: Your code would be easier for yourself and other people to read if you used consistent indentation.

Comment: I am confused why if the char buffer is setted to 4 and if type 12 characters and hit enter, the 12 character is printed back?

Comment: define a `int count = 0;` before the loop and replace the print with `printf("loop %d: %s", ++count, p);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why if I type more letters in the stdin still the string is printed back. I am assuming that if the length of the string inserted in the console is larger than the buffer will overflow and the printf will work because it stops on the termination of the string,

You get the full input echoed back by the program because the `fgets()` and `printf()` calls are inside a loop.  Each `fgets()` call will read and store as many characters as will fit in the buffer, up to and including a newline if one is in fact encountered before the available buffer space is exhausted.  If there is more data than will fit in the buffer -- because you typed more characters than can fit at once, or because you typed ahead multiple lines at hyperspeed -- then ***whatever is not read by `fgets()` remains in the stream***, waiting to be read via some future call to an I/O function.

In your program, the `printf()` echoes back the characters that were read and stored, and control then loops back to `fgets()`.  If there are more characters available to read, then it will read them, up to, again, the buffer capacity or a newline, whichever comes first.  In this way, one long line may be consumed from the standard input and echoed to the standard output over multiple iterations of the loop.

> but then what it is the point of setting a max limit as second argument to fgets?

It does exactly what it is advertized to do.  On any call, `fgets()` will write up to that many bytes into the provided buffer.

Answer (score 3):

fgets will stop when it reads the enter key OR when the buffer is full.

If you say the buffer is 8 characters long, and you type `abcdef<enter>` it will put in the buffer `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `\n` and `\0` (8 characters).

If you say the buffer is 8 characters long, and you type `abcdefgh<enter>`, it will put in the buffer `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g` and `\0` (8 characters). There is still `h<enter>` left over, which will be read the next time you call `fgets` (or `gets` or `getchar` or `scanf` etc)

Answer (score 1):

The reason because you're still getting back what you write is that `stdin` is buffered, that means when you read less characters than you actually wrote, considering you're in a `while` loop and `fgets` doesn't give any error(so you don't break in the `if` statement) you do once more the `fgets` and get the remaining chars.

Comment: `stdin` *is* line-buffered by default, but that hasn't anything in particular to do with the observed behavior.  The same  could be observed if buffering was disabled via `setvbuf()`; it would just be less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confusion is related to the behavior of the terminal rather than the behavior of the program.  When you type a single character into the terminal, it is displayed on the screen by the terminal driver.  That behavior has nothing to do with your program.  Eventually, the `fgets` function will read some data from stdin, but that may happen many seconds or minutes (or hours, if you go on a long lunch) after you initially typed the key.  Generally, the terminal driver will hold on to the data until you hit 'enter' (or 'return'), at which point a line of text will be sent to the program.  It might be easier to see if you actually write some data and see what your program is doing.  eg:

```
$ cat a.c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define buff_size 4
void
good_echo(void)
{
        char buf[buff_size];
        char *p;
        while( (p = fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) != NULL ){
                printf("good_echo read: %s\n", p);
        }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        good_echo();
        return 0;
}
$ gcc a.c
$ ./a.out
this is some text that is typed
good_echo read: thi
good_echo read: s i
good_echo read: s s
good_echo read: ome
good_echo read:  te
good_echo read: xt 
good_echo read: tha
good_echo read: t i
good_echo read: s t
good_echo read: ype
good_echo read: d
```

In the above, you can see that each call to `fgets` only consumes 3 bytes.

Comment: I think rather that the confusion is over a supposition that `fgets` reads a full line at a time, every time.  That fits with the OP's idea that there might be a buffer overflow.  Of course, `fgets` actually reads a full line in one call only if the whole line, including newline, fits in the specified amount of space.

Comment: Exactly that was my confusion @JohnBollinger